# Can I use "gilded" with an abstract concept?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, expressions, abstract-nouns

I've perused several examples of how I could use the word "gilded" but I don't see many abstract uses of it. By definition, it means to be covered in gold. Can it also be used with abstract concepts? Here's an example sentence I came up with.

The forests were gilded with the melodious voice of Lady siren

This might not be a great example. Please share one if you have one.

Comment: you did your research but need to add tags such as 'meanings' and or 'expressions' to allow an answer

Comment: You mean like "[She's only a bird in a gilded cage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCt0ioExxfo)"?  Absolutely not!

Answer (score 1):

The forests were gilded with the melodious voice of Lady siren.

Allow me:

The melodious voice of Lady Siren gilded the forest with sound.

I guess that might work. But I am not sure it is abstract. And it seems to work better in the active voice. The sound is like a layer of gold leaf.

[I rap myself on my knuckles.]

Answer (score 0):

Abstract meaning of the word [gilded](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gilded) (adj.) as described by Cambridge is:

**rich or of a higher social class.**

> "The story revolves around the gilded youth of the 1920s and their glittering lifestyles".

[Babylon online thesaurus](http://thesaurus.babylon-software.com/gilded) defines it as

**rich and superior in quality.**

> "gilded dining rooms".

In your case, it can be used as

> The forests were covered with the gilded melodious voice of Lady siren.

Comment: You got glided there. Not gilded, friend.

Comment: @Lambie thanks! I guess, it is my time to sleep, almost 1:00 am here :)

Comment: Aha, you must be in Asia. No worries, we like levity.

Comment: Next you will be telling me there was a period in US history known as the "gilded age".

Comment: @HotLicks There was, with caps, and  you can find its architecture in the form of mansions in Newport, Rhode Island.